# Page not showing when searching site:www.xyz

Tags: google, google-search-console

Yeah okay, thats the oldest question on the internet. But this is realy very weird:

I have this page: https://expeditionweather.info/

- Robots tag is set to allow
- It is added to google webmaster tools (no errors)
- It is added to google analytics (no errors)

The page is not showing up at all in google. (It is showing up in Bing and Duckduck go).

When searching with [site:www…](https://www.google.ch/search?q=site%3Aexpeditionweather.info) one dead link is showing up and that's it.

I don't understand this. Could it be that this site has been blacklisted? I have no other explanation for this. The site is online for about a month now.

Any ideas? Or am I too impatient?